# Exclude .js and .css files from spider

Tags: regex, owasp, zap

I have exclusion regexs (reasoning - I don't want to include .js and .css files):

```
.*\Q.css\E
.*\Q.js\E
```

Those are properly set to context:

> /JSON/context/view/excludeRegexs/?zapapiformat=JSON&contextName=auto-context

```
{ "excludeRegexs":"[.*\\Q.css\\E, .*\\Q.js\\E]" }
```

However once I run the spider, and query the spider results

> /JSON/spider/view/fullResults/?zapapiformat=JSON&scanId=0

I still see a lot of .js and .css files

```
{"fullResults":[{"urlsInScope":[
  {"statusReason":"OK","method":"GET","messageId":"259",
   "url":"https://contosco.com/modernizr.min.js","statusCode":"200"}
    ... lot of other .js references here ...
]} ... ]}
```

Also is there a way how to test regexs somehow without actually running the scan ?

Comment: Maybe you need to use `{ "excludeRegexs":".*\\.(css|js)$" }`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the regexes. Turns out `"context"` is the wrong place to put those exclusions (I wonder what are the `"exclusionRegexs"` in `"context"` for). The correct place where to put those regexes is in spider exclusions - i.e.

> /UI/spider/action/excludeFromScan/

Comment: They are to define the context. If you spidered / scanned just the context then those URLs should be ignored.